# PowerShell parameters with spaces causing failure in vsts

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a powershell task in vsts, the parameter I'm using contains spaces in it, this causes the PowerShell task to fail by splitting the file.

I have tried to use "`" but this removes the space making it wrong again.

(the space is between Corporate and Systems)

```
-Path "$\Corporate Systemes\Payment\Dev\src\payment.Web\app\config.js"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would be fixed using single quote `''` rather than double quotes `""`

PowerShell tries to evaluate anything inside double quotes so it's always good practice to use single quotes unless double quotes are necessary :)

#### [Get-Help about_quoting_rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: Hi, Thanks but I have already tried that: -Path '$\Corporate Systemes\Payment\Dev\src\payment.Web\app\config.js'
Did not work.

Comment: Could you share the full command that the -Path parameter is a part of? I'm not entirely sure why you have the $